# WCF PerCall inside-operation cross-caller event handling

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, event-handling

With my `WCF` service, I am solving an issue that has both performance and design effects.

The service is a stateless `RESTful` `PerCall` service, that does a lot of simple and common thins, which all work like a dandy.
But, there is one operation, that has started to scare me a lot recently, so there is the problem:

Clients make parametrized calls to the operation and the computation of the result requires lots of time to finish. But result to a call with identical parameters will always be the same, until data on the server change. And clients make an **awful LOT** of calls with exact the same parameters. The server, however, cannot predict the parameters, that the users will like, so sadly enough, the results cannot be precomputed.

So I came up with caching layer and store the result object as a key-value pair, where key represents the parameters which lead to this result. And if the relevant data change, I just flush the cache. Still simple and no problems with this.

Client calls the service, server receives the call, looks, whether the result is already cached and returns it, if so. But, if the result is not cached yet, the client starts the computation. The computation may take up to 2 minutes (average time 10-15 seconds) to finish and by that time, other clients may come and because the result is still not known to cache, each of them would start their own computation. Which is **NOT** what we really want, so there is a flag, if someone has already started the computation with this parameters this is the place in code, where other callers' code stops and waits for the computation to be finished and inserted into cache, from where each of the invoked instances will grab the result, return it to the client and dispose.
And this is the part, which I am really struggling with.

By now, my solution looks something like this (before you read further, I want to warn you, because my experience is not near decent level and I still am a big noob in all `C#`, `WCF` and related stuff... no need telling me I'm a noob, because I am fully aware of that):

```cs
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

while (true)
{
    if (Cache.Contains(parameters) || sw.Elapsed > threshold)
        break;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

...do relevant stuff here
```

As you see, there are more problems with this solution:

1. Having the loop, check and all this stuff does not only feel ugly, with many clients waiting this way, the resources tend to jump up.
2. If the operation fails (the initial caller's computation fails to deliver within the limits of threshold), I do not really know, which client has got to be next up trying the computation, or how, or even whether should I run the operation again, or return a fault to the client... 
   **EDIT:**  This is not related to synchronization, I am aware of the need for locking in some parts of my application, so my concerns are not synchronization-reated.
3. What should I do when the relevant server-side data change while invoked code is still performing computation (resulting in such result being a wrong one). ... More over, this has some other horrible effects on the application, but yeah, I am getting to the question here:

So, like most of the time, I did my homework and performed qoogling around before asking, but did not succeed in finding some guidance that I would either understand or that would suit my issues and domain.

I got a strong feel, that I have to introduce some kind of (static?) events-based-and-or-asynchronous class (call it layer if you will), that does some tricks and organizes and manages all this things in some kind of a register-to-me-and-i-will-give-you-a-poke / poke-all-registered-threads manner. But despite being able (to certain extent) to use the newly introduced tasks, `TPL`, and async-await, I not only have very limited experience on this field, more sadly, I really really need help explaining how it could come together with events (or do I even need them?)... When i try / run little things in a test-console application, I might succeed, but bringing it into this bigger environment of my `WCF` application, I struggle to get a clue.

So guys I will gladly welcome every kind of relevant thoughts, advice, guidance, links, code and criticism touching my topic.

I am aware of the fact, it might be confusing and will do my best to clear all misunderstandings and tricky parts, just ask me for doing that.

Thanks for help!